# King Parikshit & Kali Yuga

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga, kings

Why did Kali yuga need King Parikshit's permission to enter King Parikshit's kingdom?

Who authorised and empowered King Parikshit to control Kali yuga?

Comment: Nobody authorised king Parikshit. He was the king of the entire world therefore he gets to decide where the demon Kali may reside.

Comment: In fact, Parikshit wanted to kill/banish Kali, but Kali said Bhagavan Vishnu has authorized Kali to stay, but since Parikshit was king (King is representative of Bhagavan on Earth), Kali had to ask permission. So Parikshit gave him 10 literal & symbolic places to reside in - casinos, bars, brothels, butchery - being main 4 among them.